# escape character for sqlalchemy using execute()

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am dealing with a mySQL/sqlAlchemy execute statement that looks like this:

```
stmt = 'SELECT * from myTable where id=:idVar AND pct LIKE :pctVar'
args = {idVar:5, pctVar:'5%\\%'}
result = session.execute(stmt, args).fetchall()
```

How do I escape the '%'?  The above does not match "55%"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following query with explicit `ESCAPE` specification:

```
stmt = "SELECT * from myTable where id=:idVar AND pct LIKE :pctVar ESCAPE '\\'"
```

If it works, then check out [NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_backslash_escapes) option.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It works on the provided example but since my real problem is a bit more complex, I'm going to need to think  for a bit.  You wouldn't know how to set the NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES option for a single session via sqlAlchemy would you?

Comment: I do not know that, but maybe [http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/mysql.html#sql-mode] could be helpful.